# Multiplying a small matrix inside a bigger matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix

I have a 4*4 matrix and I want to divide it into 4 blocks of 2*2 matrices so that I can multiply them by a different 2*2 matrix. How do I do that in C?

A = [1 2 3 4; 2 3 4 5; 3 4 5 6; 4 5 6 7]

B = [2 3; 4 5]

I know the matrix form is from MATLAB but it's just easier to write it that way here.

Just in case you weren't clear, I wanted to multiply B, into the 4 different blocks of A, namely [1 2; 2 3], [3 4; 4 5], [3 4; 4 5] and [5 6 ;6 7]...

Here's what I've done so far that has resulted in crappy answers:

```
for (i = 1; i<= 4; i++)
{
  for (j = 1; j<=4; j++)
  {
    C[i][j] = A[i][j]*B[i-2][j-2];   
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show how you defined `A`, `B` and `C` in your C code and how you have filled in the initial values.

Comment: `B[i-2][j-2]` in your code will be `B[-1][-1]` when `i` and `j` are 1.

Comment: int A[4][4];
int  B[2][2];
int  C[4][4];
A and B are predefined as above...

Comment: That's not even valid code.  It will be much easier to help if you show [a complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Did you assign `int A[4][4] = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {4, 5, 6, 7}};` or something else?  I see your point about MATLAB syntax being more readable and that's fine for explanation.  But if we should answer your C question, we also need to see your C code.

Comment: Ahhh I see.... How do I go about fixing that? I know that if I leave it as [i] and [j] it won't work...

Comment: @5gon12eder yup that's how I defined it.. Sorry forgot to include it here as i thought it was irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you wanted to do this, had you been writing a MATLAB script.

```
A11 = [11, 12; 21, 22];
A12 = [13, 14; 23, 24];
A21 = [31, 32; 41, 42];
A22 = [33, 34; 43, 44];

A = [A11, A12; A21, A22]
B = [11, 12; 21, 22]
C = [A11 * B, A12 * B; A21 * B, A22 * B]
```

If I run the script through [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) – which I recommend as a largely compatible [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) replacement for MATLAB – it produces the following output:

```
A =

   11   12   13   14
   21   22   23   24
   31   32   33   34
   41   42   43   44

B =

   11   12
   21   22

C =

    373    396    437    464
    693    736    757    804
   1013   1076   1077   1144
   1333   1416   1397   1484
```

So let's see how it can be done in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
  int i, j;
  int A[4][4] = {
    {11, 12, 13, 14},
    {21, 22, 23, 24},
    {31, 32, 33, 34},
    {41, 42, 43, 44},
  };
  int B[2][2] = {
    {11, 12},
    {21, 22},
  };
  int C[4][4] = {
    { 0,  0,  0,  0},
    { 0,  0,  0,  0},
    { 0,  0,  0,  0},
    { 0,  0,  0,  0},
  };
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i += 2)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < 4; j += 2)
        {
          /* For each 2 x 2 block with upper-left corner at (i, j). */
          C[i + 0][j + 0] = A[i + 0][j + 0] * B[0][0] + A[i + 0][j + 1] * B[1][0];
          C[i + 0][j + 1] = A[i + 0][j + 0] * B[0][1] + A[i + 0][j + 1] * B[1][1];
          C[i + 1][j + 0] = A[i + 1][j + 0] * B[0][0] + A[i + 1][j + 1] * B[1][0];
          C[i + 1][j + 1] = A[i + 1][j + 0] * B[0][1] + A[i + 1][j + 1] * B[1][1];
        }
    }
  for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    printf("%8d%8d%8d%8d\n", C[i][0], C[i][1], C[i][2], C[i][3]);
  return 0;
}
```

Assuming you know the essentials of linear algebra, I don't think that the program will need much more explanation.  I leave it as an exercise to you to figure out the pattern in the innermost loop and re-write it as two more nested loops.  If your matrices are really just 2 × 2 then hard-coding the indices like this is probably the most readable way to write your program.  As the matrices get bigger, you'd *really* want a loop.

The output of the C program is

```
     373     396     437     464
     693     736     757     804
    1013    1076    1077    1144
    1333    1416    1397    1484
```

which happens to be confirmed by the GNU Octave script.

For tiny matrices like this, performance is almost certainly a non-issue.  If you are dealing with bigger matrices, you should be using a dedicated library such as [(C)BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/) for your linear algebra computations.  The BLAS interface has a somewhat steep learning curve and is not very convenient to use.  If you have a chance to program in C++, there are much more expressive libraries such as [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) that achieve comparable performance.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate it! I have taken Linear Algebra before and will figure the rest out.  Thanks again!  :)